# How to show from which table is data in results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find a solution how to show from which table is data.

I have two tables #_tmpImport and #_tmp_DDVI
No, I want to see from which table did data come.

Example for ID:8880 I have result P
ID:8881 I have result O

I want to see it like this

Example for ID:8880 I have result P - Import_TEST
ID:8881 I have result O - DDV

```
SELECT * FROM
 case 
     when Import_TEST.XX = 'P' then 'P'
     when DDV.XX = 'O' then 'O'
     else ' '
end as Test
FROM #_tmpImport Import_TEST
full join #_tmp_DDVI DDV ON  Import_TEST.ID=DDV.ID
```

Comment: Hey NejcP! To answer simply, no. At least not with the example you gave us, since it appears you're not actually getting data from two tables, instead you're joining them, which combines the data. But, I'm guessing I know what this is about. I am guessing you have a table that can include data and if it does not have that data, it takes it from the one higher in the "hierarchy", correct?

Comment: Please, provide sample data to fill both tables and expected result of the query. Without that, it is difficult to help you.

Comment: @tilen yes so if I can not find data in first table I am looking in another table in also there is not data  then filed is empty.

Comment: The answer is quite simple. You join on `Import_TEST.ID=DDV.ID`. To know if either table has a row that was returned in your resultset, you simply test whether those two columns are null or not null. However it is not clear if that is your actual goal.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has an extra FROM that should be replaced with a comma.

```
SELECT *,
 case 
     when Import_TEST.XX = 'P' then 'P'
     when DDV.XX = 'O' then 'O'
     else ' '
end as Test
FROM #_tmpImport Import_TEST
full join #_tmp_DDVI DDV ON  Import_TEST.ID=DDV.ID
```

Comment: Thanks for finding mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

From the information what I've gathered this is what you're trying to do:

```
SELECT *,
 case 
     when Import_TEST.XX IS NOT null then 'P'
     when DDV.XX IS NOT null then 'O'
     else null
end as Test
FROM #_tmpImport Import_TEST
full join #_tmp_DDVI DDV ON  Import_TEST.ID=DDV.ID
```

I have no way to test this at the moment, so there can be possible typos.

Comment: A comparison to NULL will return a value of "unknown", not "true" or "false". So you cannot use an expression like `Import_TEST.XX != null`. You must use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL.

Comment: Changed it according to @SMor 's instructions.